# AWS Lambda .NET 6 ARM Exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, aws-lambda, .net-6.0

We have an application that runs on AWS Lambda. Until recently we were running it on .NET Core 3.1 and x86 architecture. We have now ported it to .NET6 on ARM64 and this has brought unexpected problems, as we are randomly getting errors that we believe point to a memory shortage issue. One thesis is that GC doesn't clean up enough at certain times of the workload. On the original application (.NET Core 3.1 + x86) these errors were not present.
Does anyone have any experience with the migration to ARM and .NET6 and if it is more memory intensive or could it be a bug in the Lambda runtime? Any ideas on how to solve the problem will be gratefully received.
Thanks.

```
START RequestId: 79052b48-798c-4626-8cbb-7f9240196df6 Version: $LATEST  
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'state')
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.InvokeContinuation(Action`1 continuation, Object state, Boolean forceAsync, Boolean requiresExecutionContextFlow)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.OnCompleted(SocketAsyncEventArgs _)
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEngine.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.Execute()
at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
at System.Threading.PortableThreadPool.WorkerThread.WorkerThreadStart()
END RequestId: 79052b48-798c-4626-8cbb-7f9240196df6
REPORT RequestId: 79052b48-798c-4626-8cbb-7f9240196df6 Duration: 1051.21 ms Billed Duration: 1052 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 368 MB
RequestId: 79052b48-798c-4626-8cbb-7f9240196df6 Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: aborted Runtime.ExitError
```

Edit:
Memory problem -> This comes from our research into how to brake Lambda on the same error. Additionally, we got some other exceptions where it pointed to this problem more. The memory size in the AWS CW report is always before the error.

Comment: How have you came to conclusion that this `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` _"points to a memory shortage issue"_?

Comment: This comes from our research into how to brake Lambda on the same error. Additionally, we got some other exceptions where it pointed to this problem more. The memory size in the AWS CW report is always before the error.

Comment: Can you show us the code, its clearly telling you its a `System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'state')`

Comment: I can't because this exception doesn't come from our code base. We've been using the same application for about 3.5 years now and this bug appeared when we migrated to .NET6 and ARM. I think this exception comes from the Lambda runtime. Because we are not able to simulate this situation on local environment.

Comment: So we proved that the exception is not ours. We add "global" TryCatch block to Lambda handler and it missed this exception. It must be from Lambda runtime.